# Can I get a job in Canada with advanced degree but no work experience?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, canada, job-hunting

Currently, I am a PhD student in structural engineering. I am going to graduate this September, hopefully, and I am looking for job at the same time.

I do not consider myself to be an academician, so I decided to find job in an engineering firm.

I am interested in working in Canada, since I heard that the country is very friendly to immigrants.

Is there a way to emigrate to Canada with academic qualifications but no work history?

Comment: I've done a bit of an edit so that your question doesn't ask for opinions, which is not the format of this site, and will be more likely to be answered. If I've misunderstood, you can roll back (undo) the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You may be eligible to [emigrate via the Federal skilled workers](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/apply-factors.asp), as your Ph.D. would be 25 points of the 67 or more needed to qualify. In addition to education and experience, points are given for English and/or French skills, age, arranged employment in Canada and adaptability. You can check how many points you would have before applying to Canadian employers.  The [Government of Canada Express Entry](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/index.asp) tool has the information, contacts, and links that can facilitate settlement in the great land of Canada.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but I don't have the requisite reputation points.

You should inquire about the requirements for foreign-trained individuals to join the provincial professional body that accredits engineers in your intended province of residence. This is essential if you intend to work as an engineer in Canada.